# how to handle all requests in struts2 (including slashes)

Tags: struts2, struts, request, action, xss

I don't know how to handle all requests in struts2 (including dots and slashes). I tried:

```
action name="*"
```

and

```
action name="*/*"
```

It is good for requests that contain one slash but not for more than one slash.

Comment: what you mean by all request? do you want single action to handle all or what?

Comment: Are you talking about default action, I guess.

Comment: @Saurabh problem is that * just redirects every action but actions that have slashes

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV I have default action, but pretty much yes a default action that maps every action (including actions that have slashes) to for example first page

Comment: @pmp - i dont know if i really understood your problem. But please have a look at it, if it solves your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889322/struts2-version-2-0-x-handling-unknown-actions